# Парсинг RSS. Как вывести дату?

Tags: php

Имеется ресурс:

```
<?php 

$url = 'http://news.instaforex.com/ru/analytics/rss'; //адрес RSS ленты

$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);       //Интерпретирует XML-файл в объект

//цикл для обхода всей RSS ленты
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    echo '<h4>'.$item->title.'</h4>'; //выводим на печать заголовок статьи 
    echo $item->description.'<br>'; //выводим на печать текст статьи
}
```

В оригинале под заголовком выводится еще дата и время, в этом скрипте этого не предусмотрено. Как это сделать?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай `print_r($item)`, посмотри какое свойство отвечает за дату. Судя по XML, это `pubDate`. И выводи ее в цикле.

Должно получиться что-то типа:

```
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    echo '<h4>'.$item->title.'</h4>';
    echo $item->description.'<br>';
    echo $item->pubDate.'<br>'; // дата публикации
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает...)))
Еще вопросик. В свойстве $item->description. всегда в конце стоит ссылка. Как к ней дабавить "хвостик", например

     ?bannerid=557&refId=865

Comment: description - это кусок текста с HTML-разметкой. Чтобы в нем что-то отредактировать его тоже нужно распарсить. Смотри в сторону <a href="http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/2003-05-12">DOM в PHP</a>.

Answer (score 1):

нужно сделать `print_r`($item). И посмотреть какие там есть поля.  И обратиться  `$item->ПОЛЕ_С_ВРЕМЕНЕМ`

Answer (score 0):

```
date("d:m:Y", strtotime($strdate))
```

**Обновление**

Вернее так будет, с учетом приведенного выше условия:

```
date("d:m:Y", strtotime($item->pubDate));
```